# Node.js Installation Windows

Tags: windows, node.js

I know this may be a stupid question to ask but I want to be sure about using node.js on windows. Can I use node.js on windows with any way ?

Thanks

Comment: http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.5.5/node.exe

Comment: Scott Hanselman recently [wrote about this in his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's Windows binaries for Node itself, but it's crippled without the package manager `npm`.

---

**Update**: As of December 2011 there's a Node installer for Windows that bundles the package manager `npm`. How this rocks! http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is currently official unstable version of node.js for windows. Check out [Windows executable](http://nodejs.org/#download) in download section.

Comment: I Downloaded the executable version. But it does not open anything after clicking on this.

Comment: You need to run it through console with your program as a second parameter, for example: node.exe test.js (this will execute node.js code in test.js). You can also try to type node.exe -h in console to see available commands.

Answer (score 1):

The 0.5.x (unstable) branch comes with a [pre-compiled node.exe](http://nodejs.org/#download).  Odd branches are for development though, so it would be good enough for hacking around with (has some feature gaps), but you'll need to wait until 0.6.x for a stable "off-the-shelf" solution in windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Download the node.js binaries from http://node-js.prcn.co.cc/

Unzip it to any location, you need [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) to unzip it.

Then put the node.js bin directory into path.

Use terminal to run `node`

Answer (score 0):

With 0.4.x and earlier versions it is better to use pre-compiled binaries  from http://node-js.prcn.co.cc/ . To extract, you can use WinRar in addition to 7zip.

The 0.5.x branch barely works in Cygwin, and official support for Cygwin was dropped, so you will have to use the precompiled the native windows exe http://nodejs.org provides. NPM doesn't work with 0.5.x prior to 0.5.8, but for 0.5.8 and later there is an instruction how to get NPM running:

http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html#Installing-on-Windows-Experimental

Answer (score 0):

I installed the Node.js Azure SDK from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254279&clcid=0x409 . Open up a command prompt and type 'node' - you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have set this report on my experience setting a portable node.js ambient on Windows.
In order to leverage it you must be a full newbie.
It is not *installed* the Windows way, but instead it's made of expanded archives.
After doing the steps you end up with a command-line invironment capable of running node.js together with a few more tools usually found in UNIX-like environments.
It's here: http://bit.ly/YbGYVg